# FPPopover not showing

Tags: ios, iphone, show, popover, fppopover

I'm implementing FPPopover into my application, it was working alright until I added some code to the app delegate to manage and display the correct storyboard depending on the device throughout the app. The code I added is as follows...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [self getStoryboard];
UIViewController *initViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Init"];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = initViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
sleep(3);

return YES;}

-(UIStoryboard*) getStoryboard {
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = nil;
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];
}else{
    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
        // The iOS device = iPhone or iPod Touch
        CGSize iOSDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 480){
            // iPhone 3/4x
            storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

        }else if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 568){
            // iPhone 5 etc
            storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard_iPhone_5" bundle:nil];
        }
    }
}

return storyBoard;}
```

If I delete all this code from my App delegate the popover works perfectly... But if I add it it doesn't work... I have no idea what is going on.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Possibly, your storyboard/initViewController is being initialized to `nil`. Try adding a `NSLog(@"%@",storyboard);` and `NSLog(@"%@",initViewController);` after the respective lines of intializtion

Answer (score 0):

You don't need of this code..go in the project's general tab and set your storyboard for iPhone and iPad here:

[image: enter image description like here]

In the storyboard you can select the inital view controller..

So you can delete all your code for storyboard and initial viewController

This is the code that i use in my appDelegate :) :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    return YES;
}
```